# Updating SQLite3 database in an offline android application later

Tags: android, database, sqlite, updating

I am creating an offline android application with bus routes. The database will be updated frequently and the user should only download and import the database file only. How is this possible. My database file is stored in assets folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a signed apk and update your application on play store each time  your database changes. There is no partial update. However, play store would be sending delta updates so it is not something you have control on and should not be worried about it.